# Assign value to variable error in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new in VBA and I have some issues since very beginning. I want to create new sheet which is named same like the value in active cell. I wrote such a script:

```
Sub Makro1()

Dim country As String
Let country = ActiveCell.Value
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = country

End Sub
```

Debugger points line with `ActiveSheet.Name = country`. What is wrong with this code?

Comment: What does the debugger say?

Comment: There may already be a sheet named `country`. The `country` may contain characters not allowed in the worksheet name. The `country` may exceed the character limit for worksheet names...It would help to know specifically what your error says...

Comment: How are you defining the `ActiveCell`?  Use of this can cause problems.  Can you define the `Range()` of the cell you want the value from? (Especially if you select more than one cell)

Comment: @DavidZemens, your comment is actually an answer, and I bet my hat it's THE answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When naming worksheets, you have to keep in mind the restrictions:

- A worksheet cannot have the same name as an already-existing
  worksheet.
- A worksheet's name cannot exceed 31 characters.
- Some special characters are not allowed: this includes both forward/bacwkard slash, square brackets,    question mark, asterisk and colon.

There may be additional limitations on worksheet names, but these ones come to mind immediately because I have encountered them in the past.

This is a code snippet that handle worksheet's names validation:

```
Function validateWSName(ByVal test_name As String) As String
    'if name is blank, give a valid name to continue testing
     If test_name = "" Then test_name = "wsName"
     'if name is longer than 31 characters, then cut it off
     If Len(test_name) > 31 Then test_name = Left(test_name,31)
     'if name contains forbidden characters : \ / ? * [ or ] then eliminate them
     test_name = Replace(test_name, ":", "")
     test_name = Replace(test_name, "/", "")
     test_name = Replace(test_name, "\", "")
     test_name = Replace(test_name, "?", "")
     test_name = Replace(test_name, "*", "")
     test_name = Replace(test_name, "[", "")
     test_name = Replace(test_name, "]", "")
     'if name already exists in the worbook, then add a counter at the end
     For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
         If ws.Name = test_name Then
             keyName = ws.Name
             counter = 1
             test_name = test_name & counter
             Do While test_name = keyName
                 If counter < 10 Then
                     test_name = Left(test_name, Len(test_name)-1) & counter 
                 Else
                     test_name = Left(test_name, Len(test_name)-2) & counter
                 End If
                 counter = counter + 1
             Loop
             Exit For
         End If
     Next ws

     validateWSName = test_name
End Function
```

Your probability of getting errors there would hence reduce a lot if you add this snippet to your project and rewrite your code as follows:

```
Sub Makro1()

Dim country As String
Let country = ActiveCell.Value
Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = validateWSName(country)

End Sub
```

Comment: [I wrote some code to handle worksheet naming](https://christopherjmcclellan.wordpress.com/2013/10/25/dynamically-naming-excel-worksheets-the-headache-free-way/). Seems very relevant. It's also restricted to just 31 characters, not 34.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see you were posting an answer while I was writing mine. Would you like to join the two (I can edit yours, you arrived first ;))

Comment: @RubberDuck great example code! Thanks also for clarifying on the char limit and the certain special characters.